# Bluetooth printer connectivity with iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, printing, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to connect iphone to printer via bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117628/is-it-possible-to-connect-iphone-to-printer-via-bluetooth)

Can any body suggest how can we connect bluetooth printer with our iPhone Application.

So that i can take printout of text i have typed.

Thanks in Advance

Kamleshwar

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117628/is-it-possible-to-connect-iphone-to-printer-via-bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

iOS currently \ does not support Bluetooth printing

Comment: AirPrint

AirPrint makes it simple to print email, photos, web pages, and documents right from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. A few taps is all it takes to go from viewing it onscreen to holding a printed copy. There’s no software to download, no drivers to install, and no cables to connect.